# SwiftUI move modifier not working on IPhone and iPad iOS 15 simulator

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

The .move modifier appears not to work on iPhone 14.7.1 or iOS iPad 15.0 simulator.  It works in 14.7.1 on an iPad Pro and 14.4 on a iPad Pro, and on macCatalyst.  I have not found documentation saying that it has been deprecated in 15 though I only have access to 15 through the simulator.

I am on a M1 MacBook on 11.5.1 using Xcode 13.0 beta 5.

**UPDATE:** I downloaded the 14.5 simulator for an iPad Pro and it also didn't allow the moving of elements.  From this I assume, it is an unsupported operation on simulators.  I still don't have a clue about the iPhone.  Limited Drag and drop is supported by the iPhone from what I understand.

```
struct MoveElementsWork: View {
    @State private var elements = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                Text("\(element)")
            }
            .onMove { _,_ in
                print("Moving")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your info, your code works well for me on macos 12, xcode 13, 
target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Maybe it is different on older systems.

Comment: Thank you. Hadn't thought of trying macCatalyst.  Works for me as well.